# External hive table on top of parquet returns no data

Tags: apache-spark, hive, parquet

I created a hive table on top of a parquet folder written via spark. In one test server it is running fine and giving out results (hive version 2.6.5.196) but in production it gives no records (hive 2.6.5.179). Could someone please point out what the exact issue could be?

Comment: Did you run `MSCK REPAIR` in both cases?

Comment: yes i tried MSCK REPAIR in both cases

Answer (score 0):

If you created the table on top of an existing partition structure, you have to make it known to the table that there are partitions at this location.

```sql
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name; -- adds missing partitions
SELECT * FROM table_name; -- should return records now
```

This problem shouldn't happen if there are only files in that location, and if they are the expected format.

You can verify with:

```sql
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name; -- to see the expected format
```

Answer (score 0):

created hive table on top of a parquet folder written via spark.

1. Check for the databases that you are using is available or not using
   **show databases;**
2. check the ddl of the table that you have created on your test server and the other that is there on production
   **show create table table_name;**

Make sure that both the ddl exactly matches.

3. Do **msck repair table table_name** to load the incremental data or the data from all the partitions
4. **select * from table_name** to view records